# Debounce react-select graphql query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-select, debouncing

I'm trying to debounce graphql queries sent by my react-select component. I'm using wonka instead of rxjs but there's no tag for wonka.

```
const GraphqlQueryAsync = (query, outputFn) => (value) => {
  console.log({ value });
  return pipe(
    fromValue(value),
    // debounce(() => 5000),
    mergeMap((input) => client.executeQuery(createRequest(query, { input }))),
    map(outputFn),
    take(1),
    toPromise,
  );
};
```

React-select has a loadOptions function that calls my graphql query.

```
             <AsyncSelect
              defaultValue={value}
              styles={selectStyles(error)}
              placeholder={title}
              onChange={onChangeSelect(onChange, name, lefts)}
              defaultOptions
              loadOptions={GraphqlQueryAsync(query, outputFn)}
            />
```

My function works. However with `debounce`, it waits 5secs and still sends every value change. (ie if I type "rent", it would search for "r", "re", "ren", and "rent"). I believe this occurs because react-select repeatedly calls `loadOptions` function, creating multiple Graphql Queries. Is there anyway to allow loadOptions to continue passing the new values to the `GraphqlQueryAsync` function with debounce (ie send only "rent" search term)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve using the callback feature of loadOptions.

```
let _GraphqlQueryDebounce;
const GraphqlQueryAsync = (query, outputFn) => (value, callback) => {
  console.log({ value });
  if(_GraphqlQueryDebounce) clearTimeout(_GraphqlQueryDebounce);
  _GraphqlQueryDebounce = setTimeout(async () => callback(
    await pipe(
      fromValue(value),
      mergeMap((input) => client.executeQuery(createRequest(query, { input }))),
      map(outputFn),
      take(1),
      toPromise,
    )
  ), 5000);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can debounce the function with a delay of `1000` ms:

```
let timerId = null

const loadOptionsDebounced = (query, outputFn) => {
    clearTimeout(timerId)
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        GraphqlQueryAsync(query, outputFn)
    }, 1000)
}
```

And in your select component:

```
<AsyncSelect
    loadOptions={loadOptionsDebounced(query, outputFn)}
</AsyncSelect>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't return `GraphqlQueryAsync`'s results to `loadOptions`.

Comment: Your `setTimeout` was helpful.